# Exchange autodiscover _srv record and iPhone not working

Tags: exchange, exchange-2013, iphone, exchange-2016

I am running an on-premise Exchange 2016 server that is behind a single IP address. I followed https://jaapwesselius.com/2011/08/28/autodiscover-redirect-srv-record/ with the section "SRV Records in DNS".

I am using _srv autodiscover records (only on the primary domain do i use autodiscover cname, not anywhere else), and for each domain:

```
Primary domain under which the exchange server runs:
mail.mydomain.org => 1.2.3.4 (A record IP)
autodiscover => mail.mydomain.org (CNAME)
@ => mail.mydomain.org (MX)

Domain 1 (mydom1.com)
_autodiscover._tcp => 0 0 443 autodiscover.mydomain.org
@ => mail.mydomain.org (MX)

Domain 2 (myotherdom2.net)
_autodiscover._tcp => 0 0 443 autodiscover.mydomain.org
@ => mail.mydomain.org (MX)
```

I am running multiple domains on the box, and Outlook, Android ActiveSync and Android native exchange (also ActiveSync??) and the iPhone Exchange appstore app are all working fine.

I cannot however get native iPhone Exchange to configure on other domains using SRV records. Even manual configuration does not work (putting the server address as mail.mydomain.org).

The settings check out OK:

```
[PS] C:\Windows\system32>Get-ActiveSyncOrganizationSettings:
RunspaceId                          : 1d565c59-0361-4cbc-8c90-ff32230e4c1f
DefaultAccessLevel                  : Allow
UserMailInsert                      :
AllowAccessForUnSupportedPlatform   : False
AllowRMSSupportForUnenlightenedApps : False
AdminMailRecipients                 : {}
OtaNotificationMailInsert           :
DeviceFiltering                     :
Name                                : Mobile Mailbox Settings
IsIntuneManaged                     : False
HasAzurePremiumSubscription         : False
OtherWellKnownObjects               : {}
AdminDisplayName                    :
ExchangeVersion                     : 0.10 (14.0.100.0)
DistinguishedName                   : CN=Mobile Mailbox Settings,CN=Exchange,CN=Microsoft
                                      Exchange,CN=Services,CN=Configuration,DC=mail,DC=mydomain,DC=org
Identity                            : Mobile Mailbox Settings
Guid                                : e90a3077-3a67-4d21-b10c-190c2ace9332
ObjectCategory                      : mail.mydomain.org/Configuration/Schema/ms-Exch-Mobile-Mailbox-Settings
ObjectClass                         : {top, msExchMobileMailboxSettings}
WhenChanged                         : 17/04/2018 18:40:58
WhenCreated                         : 17/04/2018 18:40:58
WhenChangedUTC                      : 17/04/2018 14:40:58
WhenCreatedUTC                      : 17/04/2018 14:40:58
OrganizationId                      :
Id                                  : Mobile Mailbox Settings
OriginatingServer                   : dc1.mail.mydomain.org
IsValid                             : True
ObjectState                         : Unchanged
[PS] C:\Windows\system32>
[PS] C:\Windows\system32>Get-ActiveSyncDeviceAccessRule
[PS] C:\Windows\system32>
```

And Exchange Connectivity tester reports ok (via SRV record):

[image: autodiscover]

**Questions**

Any ideas please on how i can get this to work please?

How does something like Office support all those domains via its autodiscover.outlook.com dns records?

Answer (score 0):

Any error returns by [ExRCA](https://testconnectivity.microsoft.com/) (Exchange ActiveSync Autodiscover)? 
Same account experience this issue on different ActiveSync device?

Ensure DefaultAccessLevel is set to allow (**Get-ActiveSyncOrganizationSettings**), and no such device access rule to block device (**Get-ActiveSyncDeviceAccessRule**).

Comment: thanks for the pointers, have checked those and all check out OK